# How to copy to clipboard on Firefox addon popup script?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I've developed a Firefox Addon which has a feature of copying some text automatically when the popup window is open. This works fine on Chrome, but it doesn't work in Firefox, and gives me this error message.

`uncaught (in promise) DOMException: clipboard write was blocked due to lack of user activation.`

I use the clipboard API to do this.

```
navigator.clipboard.writeText(data).then(()=>{
    console.log('copied')
})
```

Any thoughts to bypass this or fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You extensions needs to have the `clipboardWrite` permission to write to the clipboard without user interaction. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions#clipboard_access

Comment: I am writing a little single-usage-hack for myself to execute in the Firefox console and get the same error message when I try to write data to the clipboard. How do I get around that?